# Comparing multiple glm models with different y-variable for best fit

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model-comparison

I have seven different GLM models. Let's say:

```r
model1 <- glm (a ~ x + y + z, data=somedata, 
               family=binomial())
model2 <- glm (b ~ x + y + z, data=somedata, 
               family=binomial())
model3 <- glm (c ~ x + y + z, data=somedata, 
               family=binomial())
...r
model7 <- glm (g ~ x + y + z, data=somedata, 
               family=binomial())
```

How can I compare the best model for fitness?

Comment: Bets in which sense? What is your goal?

Comment: a, b, c, etc..  are p-value dependent factors, and I want to check which of these factors have the best correlation with (x + y + z ).